# Buttons stacked on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons, that I would like to have one on top, and one on the button of each other, how ever when I went to see how they looked, both buttons were  inside of each other, I Cant seem to find the issue, but here's my code.

CSS

```
body { font-size: 16px; width: 600px; margin: 25px auto;  }

  button {
  color:white;
  display: inline;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 7px 35px;
  font: 300 150% langdon;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

button:hover {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
}

button:active {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  }
```

Comment: What's your (relevant) HTML?

Comment: <button class="button">Sign Up</button>
<button class="button"> Login </button>

Comment: Did you type that, or copy & paste it? Because there's no way with your CSS, or HTML, that one button should be inside another. Can you reproduce your problem, with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo?

Comment: You can see what we are getting using what you have given us from [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P74LD/).

Answer (score 7):

Currently the buttons show side by side: see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5M6vC).
If you want the next button on a new line, then use `display:block` see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5M6vC/1/).